# array list, linesearch and bubblesort. Assignment C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying again with the guidance I got from my last question. Hopefully I do this right this time. I really hope that this question ain't to broad as well, if so I apologize.

How do I create a list of 4 people (as an array) with "string name" and "int age"? What have I done wrong?

```
class person
{
public:
    string name;
    int age; 

    void SetInfo(char* _name, int _age)
    {
        name = _name;
        age = _age;
    };
};
```

What have I done wrong?

```
int main()//start of program
{
    person mylist[4];//List of people
    mylist[0].setinfo("Calle", 22)
    mylist[1].setinfo("Calle", 23)
    mylist[2].setinfo("Calle", 24)
    mylist[3].setinfo("Calle", 25)



    int index = Linearsearch(mylist, ...)

    if (index == -1)
        cout << "person not found!";
    else
        cout << "the person you searched for" << mylist[index].name << index;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```

Will this work with linesearch and bubblesort?

This is the code for the linesearch: (it is in the int main so I might as well add it here. Feel free to dissregard it)

```
int linesearch(Person p[], int n, int a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if (person[i].person age == key)
            return i;
};
```

Comment: I helps if you explain what and how doesn't work (or at least construct a minimal example that people can copy-paste and try for themselves).

Comment: _'What have I done wrong?'_ What goes wrong? Tell us please!

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my code? Have I made the class right and will with work with bubblesort and linesearch? Sorry, I will add a bit more to the post. Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named the member function as **SetInfo** but in main you name it in calls as **setinfo**

Also you forgot to place the closing brace in the class definition.

Function linesearch has to be defined as

```
int linesearch( const person p[], int n, int key)
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < n && p[i].age != key ) i++;

    return ( i == n ? -1; i );
};
```

and called in main as for example

```
int index = linearsearch(mylist, 4, 23 );
```

Again in your code names of this function do not coinside in the function call and the function definition.

Funcion SetInfo has to be declared as

```
void SetInfo( const char* _name, int _age);
```

if you use string literals as its arguments.

As for bubblesort I can say nothing because you did not show neither its definition nor its using.

And could you type names idenically in all places of the program?!!!

Comment: I think I might be able to manage to bubblesort though. Though in the end I want this to first sort the list after age then write it out and ask for a key to search for. Might be simple as hell but as noticed I'm not very good at this at all.

Comment: @Nyp0ns0pp0saurus In the function call int index = linearsearch(mylist, 4, 23 ); 4 means the size of array mylist

Comment: you should rename that 'a' parameter to 'key', because it doesn't work in this form **EDIT fixed**

Comment: @Rad1 It is not me who should rename the parameter it is he who can not even to write the same identifier correctly two times.:)

Comment: Sorry for worthless code guys. But I would not have to ask for help (witch I got, Thanks you) if I did not suck at this "/